# Etymology of "raman"

Tags: orson-scott-card, speaker-for-the-dead

The Demosthenes hiearchy of exclusion goes *Utlanning*, *Framling*, *Raman*, *Varelse*, *Djur*.

Of these, U, F, V and D are recognizable as Swedish words:

- Utlanning from *Utlänning* ("foreigner").
- Framling from *Främling* ("stranger")
- Varelse from *Varelse* ("creature", "being")
- Djur from *Djur* ("animal", "beast")

But what does "raman" refer to? No combination of a, ä or å in the two vowel positions appears to produce any recognizable Swedish word. So where did Card get this word?

(I tend to think of *Rendezvous with Rama*, but it seems like a strange place for them to pop up. Of course, the piggies *did* do everything in trees ...).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although the word [Ramen](http://translate.google.com/#sv/en/ramen) literally means "frame" in Swedish (e.g. that which can be built upon) the [Ansible Wikia](http://ansible.wikia.com/wiki/Raman) has an alternative and (to my mind) more sensible definition;

> **Raman : Although not a common word, may be constructed in Swedish from rå +
>   män, where rå indicates "coarse (not refined); brutal (crude or
>   unfeeling in manner or speech)" and män = "man" or "person." (e.g. råmän)**

Comment: Ramen means "the frame", whereas "frame" would be "ram". It is not necessarily a direct translation of the English word "frame". It is a direct translation when you mean something surrounding something else, or to frame a painting. But not when you refer to building frames as in scaffolding.

Comment: "Råmän" seems to be the correct meaning, though unlike the others, it is not a real word. "Rå" might also mean cruel or raw. But rå it is also used to describe an imprecise mythological creature of the forest. _Roe deer_ is I believe a word taken from Swedish, which has the equivalent "Rådjur", which in turn would originate from ancient Swedish. Some creature of the forest. You have the "Skogsrå" for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skogsr%C3%A5.